# In a semigroup, the product of two subsets is always a subsemigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

In a semigroup, the product of two subsets is always a subsemigroup.
 Let $A$,$B$ be two subset of semigroup G.
$$AB=\{ab:a\in A,b \in B\}$$

I try to prove this result but i haven't got any idea. So please give me a hint. Please don't give me any answers.

Comment: I don't understand the claim.  Say $A,B$ each have only one element.  Then their product also has only one element.   Is a one element subset a subsemigroup?  It's not necessarily closed under the product...

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets

Comment: @lulu, i found this statement in Wikipedia  But I don't know if it is true.

Comment: @CloudJR You must be reading something wrong. If you quote exactly the sentence at that link that  you think says the product of two subsets is a subsemigroup  someone will tell you what that sentence really means...

Comment: Well, I gave what looks to me like a counterexample.  If $A=\{a\}$ and $B=\{b\}$ then the product is the single element subset $\{ab\}$.  Now in that subset we can at least multiply $ab$ by itself, getting $(ab)^2$.  Why should that be equal to $ab$?

Comment: Maybe Wikipedia meant that the product of two subsemigroups (instead of subsets) is a subsemigroup?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  Well, the wiki article does say "In a semigroup, the product of two subsets is always a subsemigroup;"   which is hard to misinterpret.  Of course, that does not make it true.

Comment: @ lulu seems fine to me. But please check generalization to semigroup section

Comment: Here is a link to the subsection regarding [product of semigroup subsets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets#Generalization_to_semigroups), to which the OP is referring. It does appear to be incorrect.

Comment: @CloudJR Ok, it says that -  I didn't scroll down far enough. You  can't believe everything you read on the internet.

Comment: @David, i am actually working on a problem involving product of subset of group A and cardinality of that subset is greater than half the order of the G. Now claim is A^2 is G. I proved other axioms but proving A^2 is closed seems very hard . So i check that section but when i looks at this result it seems more general, so  i tried but no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have an XY problem. The OP asked about proving something that's obviously false. In a comment it turns out what the OP really wants is this:

> > If $G$ is a finite group, $A\subset G$ and $|A|>|G|/2$ then $A^2=G$.

Of course $A^2$ might mean $\{a^2:a\in A\}$, but then the result is clearly false, since $|A^2|\le|A|$. Assuming instead  that $A^2=\{ab:a,b\in A\}$ it's true by a simple counting argument:

Fix $x\in G$ annd define $$B=\{a^{-1}x:a\in A\}.$$Since $G$ is a group, $$|A|+|B|=2|A|>|G|.$$So $A\cap  B\ne\emptyset$, and if $b=a^{-1}x\in B\cap A$ then $x=ab$.

Answer (score 3):

No, the product of two subsets has no reason to be a subsemigroup. What is true however, is that $\mathcal{P}(S)$, equipped with the product you defined, is a semigroup.

Comment: Can you give me a counter example , this statement is given in Wikipedia page. If it is false please someone edit that page too

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets

Comment: @CloudJR Huh? It doesn't say that the proofuct of  two sets is a subsemigroup at that link.

Comment: Wikipedia says exactly the same thing as me: the operation is defined on the set of subsets of a semigroup (or of a group) and defines a semigroup. This does not mean that $AB$ is a subsemigroup. Take $S = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$, $A  = B = \{1\}$. Then $AB = \{2\}$ is not a subsemigroup of $S$.

Comment: See the  section , generalization to semigroup

Comment: Here again is a link to the specific subsection that the OP is referring to entitled [Generalization to Semigroups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_group_subsets#Generalization_to_semigroups).

Comment: Wikipedia has just been corrected...

Comment: Great!............